# Grouping Bars Using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am  trying to write a program that represents data from multiple csv files. The x axis is for each year, and there are potentially 6 different bars that will be within each year. The problem is that some bars have a value <0.1, which means I want that bar skipped.

Here is a picture of what my generated graphs currently looks like:

[image: graph with spaces for bars with values of 0.0]

I figured out how to leave that bar's space blank, but I am having trouble trying to get all the graphs within a year to be grouped together.

Here is my current code:

```
def process_data(file_paths, district):
    dfs = [pd.read_csv(file_path) for file_path in file_paths]
    
    # Assume the first CSV is for 2018-19, the second for 2019-20, and so on

    enrollment_percentages_by_year = {}
    discipline_percentages_by_year = {}
    total_students_by_year = {}
    discipline_total_by_year = {}

    for i, df_district in enumerate(dfs):
        # Assume the order of CSV files corresponds to academic years
        year = academic_years[i]

        total_students = df_district[(df_district['DIST_NAME'] == district) & (df_district['OFFENSE_CODE'] == 'ALL') & (df_district['GROUP_LABEL'] == 'All Students')]['DENOM'].sum()

        enrollment_percentages = {}
        discipline_percentages = {}
        discipline_total = 0

        for race in races:
            race_count = df_district[(df_district['DIST_NAME'] == district) & (df_district['OFFENSE_CODE'] == 'ALL') & (df_district['GROUP_LABEL'] == race)]['DENOM'].sum()
            percentage = round((race_count / total_students) * 100, 2)
            enrollment_percentages[race] = percentage

            discipline_count = df_district[(df_district['DIST_NAME'] == district) & (df_district['OFFENSE_CODE'] == 'ALL') & (df_district['GROUP_LABEL'] == race)]['NUMER'].sum()
            if race_count != 0:
                discipline_percentage = round((discipline_count / race_count) * 100, 2)
            else:
                discipline_percentage = 0.0
            discipline_percentages[race] = discipline_percentage

        enrollment_percentages_by_year[year] = enrollment_percentages
        discipline_percentages_by_year[year] = discipline_percentages
        total_students_by_year[year] = total_students
        discipline_total_by_year[year] = discipline_total

    return enrollment_percentages_by_year, discipline_percentages_by_year, total_students_by_year, discipline_total_by_year

def generate_grouped_graph(discipline_percentages_by_year, district, formatted_timestamp, total_students_by_year, discipline_total_by_year):
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))  # Adjust the figure size as needed
    bar_width = 0.13  # Width of each bar
    x = range(len(academic_years))

    for i, race in enumerate(races):
        discipline_percentages = [discipline_percentages_by_year[year][race] for year in academic_years]
        positions = [pos + i * bar_width for pos in x]

        # Skip bars with a value of 0.0
        non_zero_discipline_percentages = [(pos, rate) for pos, rate in zip(positions, discipline_percentages) if rate != 0.0]

        if non_zero_discipline_percentages:
            positions, heights = zip(*non_zero_discipline_percentages)
            ax.bar(positions, heights, bar_width, label=f'{race}')

    for rect in ax.patches:
        yval = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2, yval, round(yval, 1), va='bottom', ha='center', color='black', weight='bold')

    ax.set_xlabel('Year')
    ax.set_ylabel('%')
    ax.set_title(f'Discipline Percentages by Race in {district} District (Grouped by Year)')
    
    # Set x-axis ticks at the center of each group
    ax.set_xticks([pos + (len(races) - 1) * bar_width / 2 for pos in x])
    ax.set_xticklabels(academic_years)
    
    ax.legend()
    
    # Set y-axis limit based on the maximum discipline rate
    ax.set_ylim(0, 50)

    plt.tight_layout()

    results_folder = f'Discipline_Grouped_Graphs_{formatted_timestamp}'
    os.makedirs(results_folder, exist_ok=True)

    image_path = os.path.join(results_folder, f'{district}_grouped_discipline_percentages_plot.png')
    plt.savefig(image_path, format='png')

    plt.close()

    return image_path
```